# What are the cuts of the graph by the planes of the system

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

while solving from a multivariable calculus textbook I encountered this question: ''what are the cuts of the graph by the planes of the system?, explain this through $z =\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ and draw an adequate sketch''.

I can hardly comprehend the phrase ''what are the cuts of the graph by the planes of the system?'' which system?

Comment: Maybe you have some system somewhere whose solutions are planes? Whatever the planes may be, the "cuts" are just the intersection of the graph with said planes. For example, the planes $\{z = z_0\}$ cut the graph at circumferences of radius proportional to the height of the plane above the origin: $\{x^2+y^2 = z_0^2, z = z_0\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Intersection with plane $z = {z_0}$:
$$\begin{gathered}
  \sqrt {{x^2} + {y^2}}  = {z_0} \hfill \\
  {x^2} + {y^2} = {\left( {{z_0}} \right)^2} \hfill \\
  x = {z_0}\cos (t) \hfill \\
  y = {z_0}\sin (t) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}$$
Intersecting curve:
$$c(t) = ({z_0}\cos (t),{z_0}\sin (t),{z_0})$$

[image]

Intersection with plane $y = {y_0}$:
$$\begin{gathered}
  \sqrt {{x^2} + {{\left( {{y_0}} \right)}^2}}  = z \hfill \\
  {x^2} + {\left( {{y_0}} \right)^2} = {z^2} \hfill \\
  {z^2} - {x^2} = {\left( {{y_0}} \right)^2} \hfill \\
  x = {y_0}\sinh (t) \hfill \\
  z = {y_0}\cosh (t) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}$$
Intersecting curve:
$$c(t) = ({y_0}\sinh (t),{y_0},{y_0}\cosh (t))$$

[image]

Intersection with plane $x = {x_0}$:
$$\begin{gathered}
  \sqrt {{{\left( {{x_0}} \right)}^2} + {y^2}}  = z \hfill \\
  {\left( {{x_0}} \right)^2} + {y^2} = {z^2} \hfill \\
  {z^2} - {y^2} = {\left( {{x_0}} \right)^2} \hfill \\
  y = {x_0}\sinh (t) \hfill \\
  z = {x_0}\cosh (t) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}$$
Intersecting curve:
$$c(t) = ({x_0},{x_0}\sinh (t),{x_0}\cosh (t))$$
[image]